# how will the precedence of && and != work in a logical statement?

Tags: pointers, operator-precedence

While (ptr ! =NULL && dptr! = NULL && dptr->next! =NULL)

In this code if the pointer dptr is NULL will it work or will terminate?

Comment: What language? Please use the appropriate tag.

Comment: How could it terminate? You don't call any termination function.

Answer (score 0):

If the statement is true or not is actually based not only on dptr but also on ptr and dptr->next. If the statement is true - the content if the while-loop will be executed.

The substatements (your camparisons to not NULL) are checked one after another - if one is false, the other will not be executed. This is true for most programming languages. Though I haven't checked with all.
Logical && as well as || have some inherent mechanism for fast return. They both go step by step from left to right substatement. (Plus () ). With && the check is aborted on the first false statement. With || the check is aborted on the first true statement. The other checks won't be reached.

So your statement will never check dptr->next != NULL for the case that dptr is actually NULL. So your statement is safe from access to NULL pointers.